# CSS target OL's second element

Tags: css

I have the following `ol`:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="/home">home</li>
<li><a href></a></li>
<li><a href="/registration">registration</li>
</ol>
```

I need to target the second child of the `ol` and hide it, however whatever I try - it is unsuccesful.

I have trie the following:

```
ol.breadcrumb:second-child{
    display: none;
}

ol.breadcrumb.float-right:nth-child(2){
    display: none;
}

ol.breadcrumb.float-right:nth-of-type(2){
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools (`ctrl`+`shift`+`j` to open it), on the tab which shows DOM version of current page (`Elements` tab in Chrome) do a `ctrl`+`f`, then type your selector `ol.breadcrumb:nth-child(2)` query and see if that will bring up the expected element. If not then go for another one.

Answer (score 2):

To target the second child of `ol`, try this :

```
ol.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2){
  display: none;
}
```

You also need to close your `a` elements in your code.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmawksd3/2/)

Comment: Beat me to it, I've deleted my answer as same as yours!

Comment: Haha, it's the game of SO ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`ol.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) { ... }` would work -- you had the `.float-right` which you don't have in the HTML.  `nth-child(2)` is for the `li`, not `ol`

You also need to close your `<a>` properly for line 1 and 3.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mwmhd6cc/

I used a background color instead of display none to show the effect, but you can just change it to `display: none`